# Different 100% table width than divs 100% width

Tags: html, css

I am working on a new site: http://www.artexe.sk/cpm.

The "right side" of website consists of 9 images absolutely positioned in a relative `div`. It has width set to `100%` and each image in row should have width of `33%`.

Now under these images we have `#footer` which is `div` and it has width `100%`. **PROBLEM:** In this `div`, there is a `table` which also has width of `100%`

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

When I take a look on my laptop `#footer` has width `1012px` and `table` has `1011px`! How is this even possible? When you take a look at it by design the right side of image should be the same as right side of first `td` in the `table`.

I also have another question: when I try to set a fixed width of `1012px` on the table so every `td` has a width of `337px` (`33%`). The images have also width of `33%` and their width in pixels is `334px`! How is this possible?

EDIT!!!
This is css for right side of website

```
#rightbody {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 75%;
}
```

when i delete width: 75%, the width of table is the same as the parents div but that width is important

Comment: Why use a table? It is not data. Use divs whcih are floated.

Comment: I am using table because of td is displayed as table cell, it has its height and i can use VERTICAL ALIGN MIDDLE

Comment: You can use display: inline-block and vertical-align: middle
http://fiddle.jshell.net/nE3rY/6/

Comment: but i would like to know why 33% != 33% with different positioning ... but thank you for your answer, i will definitely try it

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
table-layout:fixed
```

to your table's css. I had almost the same problem before and it worked for me. 
Hope this helps.